# How can I compare a string with predefined string using strcmp

Tags: c++

How can I compare a string with predefined string using `strcmp`?

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char user[12];
char pass[12];
char usr[4][12] = {"nathan", "marco", "denz", "ana"};
char pss[4][12] = {"admin", "two", "sad", "three"};
int x, y;
main() {
  clrscr();
  for (x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    cout << "-";
  }
  cout << "Username: ";
  scanf("%s", &user);
  cout << "Password: ";
  scanf("%s", &pass);
  for (y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
    if ((strcmp(user, usr[x]) == 0) && (strcmp(pass, pss[x]) == 0)) {
      cout << "Log-in Successful";
      break;
    }  // if
    else {
      cout << "Log-in Failed! Try Again!";
      break;
    }  // else
  }    // for
  getch();

}  // main
```

Comment: Your question could use some additional details, like what problem you're encountering.  However, take a look at your if/else statement.  Do you see anything funny with it?

Comment: Im literally confuse on using strcmp for predefined and an input from user @1201ProgramAlarm

Comment: If possible, discard character arrays and use `std::string`. Also take note that both paths through `for (y=0; y<5; y++)` `break`, so only one iteration of the loop will ever be run.

Comment: Return type of `main` must be explicitly `int`

Comment: There is no such header as `iostream.h`

Comment: To keep people focused on the question you asked, it helps to produce a [mcve]. Based on the question, I would guess such an example could have maybe five lines in the `main` function. (Define the string, then use an if-else statement to compare it with a string literal.)

Answer (score 1):

The `strcmp()` method takes two arguments, in your case the first would be the `password` or `username` (key) that will be compared against the second word given being `user input` (value).
So for example

```
strcmp(key, value);
```

This returns an integer value, 0 if the strings match and either a negative or positive depending on the ASCII value of the characters if they don't match.

Comment: `strcmp` **doesn't** return a boolean, it returns an `int`. <0, 0, >0.

Comment: Yep @JavierSilvaOrtíz see above.

Comment: so like if(strcm(usr,user)==0) && strcmp(pss,pass)==0) ?

Comment: Yep! @MiniProgrammer

Comment: What about the [x] for? is it neccessary? @samblack

Answer (score 0):

Your code has many problems:

- In your `for` loop, you use `y` as the counter but in the code inside the loop. you use `x`.

  - Given that `x` is 10 at that point, you always compare an inexistant user/password since your arrays contains 4 of those.
  - Also the loop limit is 5 instead of 4 so you loop one time too many. Better to use a single constant and even better let the compiler compute the size (using `sizeof` or `std::size`).
- If the first password tested is wrong you display an error that the password is invalid without testing the 3 other password (since you break out of the loop).

Comment: Okay so im gonna use size_t or sizeof ? for inputs ?